# AES-128-CBC encryption in CryptoJS

Tags: php, encryption, cryptojs

I am trying to convert below encryption function created in PHP using CryptoJS but it is not returning same encrypted text. Can anyone help me doing this?

PHP function:

```
function encrypt($data,  $key)
{
    $algo = 'AES-128-CBC';

    $iv = substr($key, 0, 16);
    $cipherText = openssl_encrypt(
        $data,
        $algo,
        $key,
        OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
        $iv
    );
    $cipherText = base64_encode($cipherText);

    return $cipherText;
}
```

CryptoJS Function

```
var key = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx123456";
var IV = key.substr(0, 16);
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("ABC", key, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, iv: IV });
```

Comment: If you use `AES-128-CBC` on the PHP side, you must consistently apply a 16 bytes key (which is not currently happening on the JavaScript side). Also, on the JavaScript side, key and IV must be passed as `WordArray` (using an [encoder](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders) suitable for the data, e.g. Utf8). Note that applying the key as IV is generally insecure.

Comment: It would help if you would post some example plaintext / ciphertext pairs for both (preferably in hexadecimals), not everybody has a good setup ready to compile & run both blocks of code. Obviously these are not [mcve]s either.